# Auto run PHP script in windows

Tags: php, windows

How can I run a PHP file everyday in windows without using task scheduler or cron? I have used Jquery but I have realized it does not solve the problem for me. Is there any way I could use PHP without using javascript, jquery or windows.

Comment: why without task scheduler or cron? basically, those are the tools made for this, exactly this and only this use case.

Comment: Okay is there anyway I can use another language like javascript or jquery to read the system time(server time) and call that PHP file?

Comment: for that, you can use any language with datetime-functions that is able to execute commands. which is basically almost every popular language. but i'm still not clear about why to build your own cron-system instead using an existing one - could you possibly elaborate as to why you don't want to use cron/etc.?

Comment: Am building a web based application and I was wondering I would use php itself or any other language without using any external program.

Answer (score 0):

I found phpjobscheduler and it solved my problem. [phpjobscheduler](http://www.phpjobscheduler.co.uk/)